# Need to replace emoji characters with their Unicode value

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode, emoji

I'm new to python and currently i'm working with project which requires to analyse emojis in user comments.
Their I need to replace emojis in a string with their unicode values.
Here is my code

```
import re

RE_EMOJI = re.compile('[\U00010000-\U0010ffff]', flags=re.UNICODE)

def strip_emoji(text):
    return RE_EMOJI.sub(r'', text)

print(strip_emoji('hi '))
```

Sample output

```
 hi
```

This code removes the emojis on string, But I need to replace them with their unicode value.

Expected output

```
hi U0001F600 U0001F601
```

Comment: They are already their Unicode values. It seems that you're looking for another way to represent your string not replacing them.

Comment: yes, some how I need to get that expected string as output